# R: comparing jglmm models

Tags: r, mlm

When using lmer, one can compare two models using anova:

```
mod.ld.frq = lmer(ln_rt_offset ~ 1 + lfrq + 
                  (1 + lfrq | PID) + (1| Item), 
                  data=ldfw.std)
mod.ld.frq.dur = lmer(ln_rt_offset ~ 1 + lfrq + duration + 
                  (1 + lfrq | PID) + (1| Item), 
                  data=ldfw.std)
anova(mod.ld.frq, mod.ld.frq.dur)
```

What is the equivalent for jglmm, e.g.:

```
jmod.ld.frq = jglmm(ln_rt_offset ~ 1 + lfrq + 
                  (1 + lfrq | PID) + (1| Item), 
                  data=ldfw.std)
jmod.ld.frq.dur = jglmm(ln_rt_offset ~ 1 + lfrq + duration + 
                  (1 + lfrq | PID) + (1| Item), 
                  data=ldfw.std)
```

If I try using anova, I get an error like this:

```
anova(jmod.ld.frq, jmod.ld.frq.dur.phon)
Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "jglmm"
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Can you tell us what `jglmm` is/what package it comes from? (presumably https://github.com/mikabr/jglmm ?)

Comment: Yes, that's right. It let's you use julia which I'm trying to use to avoid convergence problems with a very large dataset... So I'm trying to figure out how to do a likelihood ratio test on 2 julia models (jglmm objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to exist, but I wrote a crude `anova` function based on the existing `jglmm::extractAIC.jglmm` method, which has to extract the same information (df, log-likelihood) from the model.

```r
library(JuliaCall)
my_anova <- function(m1, m2) {
   julia_assign("model1", m1$model)
   julia_assign("model2", m2$model)
   df1 <- julia_eval("dof(model1);")
   df2 <- julia_eval("dof(model2);")
   loglik1 <- julia_eval("loglikelihood(model1);")
   loglik2 <- julia_eval("loglikelihood(model2);")
   ddf <- df1 - df2
   ddev <- 2*(loglik1 - loglik2)
   c(ddev, ddf, pchisq(ddev, ddf, lower.tail = FALSE))
}
```

`jglmm` results:

```r
m1 <- jglmm(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject),lme4::sleepstudy)
m2 <- jglmm(Reaction ~ 1 + (Days|Subject),lme4::sleepstudy)
my_anova(m1, m2)
## [1] 2.353654e+01 1.000000e+00 1.225640e-06
```

Compare with `lme4`:

```r
library(lme4)
m1B <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject),lme4::sleepstudy)
m2B <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (Days|Subject),lme4::sleepstudy)
anova(m1B, m2B)
```

Results:

```
refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
Data: lme4::sleepstudy
Models:
m2B: Reaction ~ 1 + (Days | Subject)
m1B: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
    npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
m2B    5 1785.5 1801.4 -887.74   1775.5                         
m1B    6 1763.9 1783.1 -875.97   1751.9 23.537  1  1.226e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The `lme4` results are much prettier, but the key components (change in deviance, change in df, p-value) are the same.

On second thought,  we could have done this more easily by calling the `logLik` accessor method for the fit (the returned information includes both the log-likelihood and the df) and putting that into the `my_anova()` function ...

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you very much. Does it make sense to take the abs() of ddf and ddev in case model 1 is the smaller model? There are also two julia functions that seem promising -- MixedModels.likelihoodratiotest and StatsModels.lrtest. If/when I get them working, I'll post an update, but your solution is great. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe: I was slightly worried about the case where ddf and ddev have 'wrong' signs (indicating that something is wonky). Also a question about whether you want to worry about preventing people from doing `anova()` on REML fits, pretty-printing, etc.. Also worth asking whether you'd rather do more coding in R or in Julia ...

Comment: Thank you, Ben Bolker. I'll think about those issues. I'm maybe an intermediate R programmer and a complete novice with Julia, so I'm learning a LOT from this and will think about these issues you raise. Thanks again!